# Why is the Paste button in a Rich Text Field disabled?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager

We have a General component in Tridion 2013 SP 1 which has a Rich Text Field field called Body.

Opening the component in Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.90 m) and selecting the field Body, the Paste button on the ribbon toolbar is not enabled.

I checked the General schema and checked the "Edit Formatting Features" of the Body field but "Paste" is not included in the list of Formatting Features.

I opened the component in Firefox (37.0.2) and selected the field and the "Paste" button is highlighted. I paste something in the field then the "Paste" button disappears again.

I couldn't open the component in IE11 because it's not been tested there.

As far as I'm aware, this is not a user permission issue. Is there a reason for this? Is there anywhere I can start debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste stopped working in Chrome a couple of releases back, when google blocked access to the clipboard from Javascript. Firefox is on its way to block it too - though there are some steps you [can take](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B0393E1F-2F38-4CC0-841C-44D78AAE0B33) to configure it so that it works. It works normally in IE.

We are revisiting/re-designing/re-implementing this functionality for our next release, and it's unlikely we'll change it in the current release. If you need a solution *today* I'd recommend looking at the excellent "[Paste Special Cross Browser Extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/pastespecial.aspx)" on Tridion World.

Seriously, look at it. [It cost me an iPad](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/PowerPaste) :p

Comment: but it didn't reach at my address.

Comment: Talk to Greg then!

Comment: sorry Nuno, just confirmed :)  he got that, i was totally unaware.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting this verbatim from the April 2015 edition of the SDL Support newsletter:

SDL has released a hotfix for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 hotfix rollup 1 (HR#1) to address the GUI issues caused by Chrome v42 where you are no longer able to open non-localized Components and Pages.

The Tridion 2013 SP1 HR#1 hotfix is CME_2013.1.1.88718, and can be downloaded from here: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx (SDLTridionWorld login required).

Please follow all instructions in the hotfix README.txt file carefully. If you encounter other issues with Chrome after applying the hotfix, notify Customer Support by opening a new support incident.